# A question regarding internet protocol traffic

Tags: network-security

when we download any file from internet which internet traffic protocol is observed?
for example if we download a movie from a website will it be FTP protocol traffic or HTTP protocol traffic or anything else?

Comment: It depends on how you're downloading it. If you're streaming it in your browser, it's most likely HTTP/HTTPS (if it starts with http:// or https://). If you're downloading it with FileZilla or using the ftp:// URL, it's FTP.

Comment: If we goto a website and start downloading any file from server: example movie, setup-file of an application, ebook, etc...
then what kind of traffic would that be? Should i call it Http downloading traffic, Ftp downloading traffic, or what?
I know that it is client-server interaction, but what kind of traffic is going on...?

Comment: I've answered that already. Did you read what I wrote? **It depends on how you're downloading it** seems very clear, and I don't know how else to say it. It could be HTTP/HTTPS, FTP, or another protocol, **depending on what exactly is being downloaded and how it's being requested**.

Answer (score 0):

> when we download any file from internet which internet traffic protocol is observed?

The two most common "traffic protocols" you'll encounter on the Internet for downloading files (in the context of the use case you provided) are [UDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) and [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol). However this is a massive oversimplification.

> for example if we download a movie from a website will it be FTP protocol traffic or HTTP protocol traffic or anything else?

Websites - places observable on the "World Wide Web" - will most often be using the [HTTP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) (or HTTPS in the case of a TLS/SSL encrypted connection). The HTTP protocol exists at the [application layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_layer), which is layer number 7 in the [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model). You should familiarise yourself with the various layers which make up network communication in order to gain a deeper understanding of:

- the various protocols that exist
- where they are used
- what their purpose is
- which applications make use of them, or "speak" the protocol

However, your browser is capable of "speaking" other protocols as well such as FTP, so it may in fact be talking to an FTP server hosting movie files or any other type of file for that matter.